# With JMeter, if we increase load,is it possible that our tested server crash?

Tags: jmeter

If suppose I will run load testing with 5000 threads or may be more ,
Will the main server under test crash at a certain level.

Comment: Err, it is the purpose of JMeter to find that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EJP said, it is JMeter purpose to find the limit of tested application and how it will react under performance.

So yes it is perfectly possible.

You should read JMeter Manual.

Comment: my connection log showing no activity,but just the db meter get up and down.I want to know which meter(e.g cpu performance or db log) should i notice ,so that I will know that i have to increase certain operation to crash the server

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any kind of performance tests (load, stress, soak etc) you will want to know at what point your application server falls over i.e. its breaking point.

Once you've found out what your upper limit is, start dialing back the number of threads until you find your application's "sweet spot" for example CPU usage <80% & >70%